# Fody + Mono: the requested feature is not implemented

Tags: c#, .net, mono, fody

I'm trying to compile a C# project using Mono and am getting the following exception during compilation using xbuild:

```
Error: Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
Exception:
  The requested feature is not implemented.
StackTrace:
  at Mono.Cecil.Mdb.MdbReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition,System.IO.Stream) <0x00017>
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition,Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters) <0x000cb>
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModuleFrom (Mono.Cecil.PE.Image,Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters) <0x000e7>
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.IO.Stream,Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters) <0x00063>
  at ModuleWeaver.GetTemplateModuleDefinition () <0x00133>
  at ModuleWeaver.ImportAssemblyLoader (bool) <0x00027>
  at ModuleWeaver.Execute () <0x00113>
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object) <0x0004c>
  at InnerWeaver.ExecuteWeavers () <0x002cb>
  at InnerWeaver.Execute () <0x00123>

Source:
  Mono.Cecil.Mdb
TargetSite:
  Mono.Cecil.Cil.ISymbolReader GetSymbolReader(Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition, System.IO.Stream)
  (Hybrasyl)
```

The project is using Fody, which appears to be what's throwing the error. From what I can tell [Fody should support Mono](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/wiki/Mono). I'm using the latest version of Mono (v4.0.1.0), Fody (v1.28.3.0), and Costura Fody (v1.3.3.0).

Q1: What feature is the compiler claiming is not implemented? I'm having trouble understanding the error message.

Q2: Is this expected behavior? I'm having trouble finding references to Fody's status with respect to Mono support and am not sure if this is truly missing support or whether I'm doing something incorrectly. I'm new to the .NET + Mono world so let me know if I need to clarify further.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with Mono 3.12 and see if it works there? I've seen a possibly related issue with cecil on Mono 4.0.

Comment: can u try the newest of fody and costura